# How to get the trending topics of twitter with php?

Tags: php, twitter

Can you give me a php script who return the firts 3 trending topic of twitter? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you should be asking people to write code for you, but anyway, here you are.

```
<?php

$request    = file_get_contents( 'http://search.twitter.com/trends/current.json' );
$json       = json_decode( $request, true );
$trends     = $json[ 'trends' ];
$keys       = array_keys( $trends );
$trends     = $trends[ $keys[ 0 ] ];
$trends     = array(

     $trends[ 0 ][ 'name' ],
     $trends[ 1 ][ 'name' ],
     $trends[ 2 ][ 'name' ]

);
```

**NOTE: Above used Twitter API is no longer active**

Comment: If you want an associative array out of `json_decode`, you can make the second paramater `true` instead of getting the object and then casting it.

Comment: +1. Forgot about that parameter :)